# Using a pure function in a Haskell monad / left-lifting?

Tags: haskell, monads, idioms, lifting

Consider the following function:

```
foo =
  [1,2,3] >>=
  return . (*2) . (+1)
```

For better readability and logic, I would like to move my pure functions `(*2)` and `(+1)` to the left of the return. I could achieve this like this:

```
infixr 9 <.
(<.) :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> c)
(<.) f g = g . f

bar =
  [1,2,3] >>=
  (+1) <.
  (*2) <.
  return
```

However, I don't like the right-associativity of `(<.)`.

Let's introduce a function `leftLift`:

```
leftLift :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> a -> m b
leftLift f = return . f

baz =
  [1,2,3] >>=
  leftLift (+1) >>=
  leftLift (*2) >>=
  return
```

I quite like this. Another possibility would be to define a variant of `bind`:

```
infixl 1 >>$
(>>$) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> b) -> m b
(>>$) m f = m >>= return . f

qux =
  [1,2,3] >>$
  (+1) >>$
  (*2) >>=
  return
```

I am not sure whether that is a good idea, since it would not allow me to use `do` notation should I want that. `leftLift` I can use with `do`:

```
bazDo = do
  x <- [1,2,3]
  y <- leftLift (+1) x
  z <- leftLift (*2) y
  return z
```

I didn't find a function on Hoogle with the signature of `leftLift`. Does such a function exist, and, if, what is it called? If not, what should I call it? And what would be the most idiomatic way of doing what I am trying to do?

---

Edit: Here's a version inspired by @dunlop's answer below:

```
infixl 4 <&>
(<&>) :: Functor f => f a -> (a -> b) -> f b
(<&>) = flip fmap

blah =
  [1,2,3] <&>
  (+1) <&>
  (*2) >>=
  return
```

I should also add that I was after a `bind`-variant, because I wanted to write my code in point-free style. For `do`-notation, I guess I don't need to "pretend" that I'm doing anything monadic, so I can use `let`s.

Comment: I find myself using `=<<` more often than `>>=`, to stay consistent with composition and ordinary application. That nicely avoids the direction reversal in the first example.

Comment: That's nice; I wasn't aware of it. I can then write `return . (*2) . (+1) =<< [1,2,3]`. And, yes, as @user2297560 says below, readability is all quite subjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every `Monad` is a `Functor` (and an `Applicative` too). Your `(>>$)` is (flipped) `fmap`.

```
GHCi> :t fmap
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
GHCi> :t (<$>) -- Infix synonym for 'fmap'
(<$>) -- Infix synonym for 'fmap'
  :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
GHCi> fmap ((*2) . (+1)) [1,2,3]
[4,6,8]
GHCi> (*2) . (+1) <$> ([1,2,3] >>= \x -> [1..x])
[4,4,6,4,6,8]
```

(By the way, a common name for flipped `fmap` is `(<&>)`. That is, for instance, what *lens* calls it.)

---

If you are using do-notation, there is little reason to use any variant of `fmap` explicitly for this kind of transformation. Just switch your `<-` monadic bindings for let-bindings:

```
bazDo = do
  x <- [1,2,3]
  let y = (+1) x
      z = (*2) y
  return z
```

```
bazDo = do
  x <- [1,2,3]
  let y = (+1) x
  return ((*2) z)
```

Comment: I could define my `(>>$)` in terms of `fmap` then. I wouldn't want to use `(<$>)` directly, since it spoils the sequential appearance. I would like my code to read as "take numbers out of `[1,2,3]`, add `1` to them, and multiply them with `2` (my actual code would be larger than that).

Comment: @marc_r The easiest way of maintaining the sequential appearance in this kind of monadic code is using do-notation.

Comment: Thus my `leftLift` function. I'll edit my post to include the `do` version.

Comment: @marc_r I have edited the answer to add a suggestion related to that.

Comment: `let`s are a possibility. I am unsure about which version is the nicest. I was also thinking that my `leftLift` could perhaps be of more general usefulness (although I don't know yet how).

Comment: @marc_r Between your `leftLift` and your `(>>$)`, I would definitely pick `(>>$)`. In the relvant use case here (i.e. left-to-right pointfree monadic code), you only need `leftLift` because you have used `(>>=)` beforehand, and you can replace them both with `(>>$)`. In other situations in which it might be used, I would just write `return . f` rather than using a special-purpose combinator like `leftLift`.

Answer (score 1):

> For better readability...

That's going to be subjective as people disagree on what constitutes readable.

That being said, I agree that sometimes it's easier to understand data transformations when they are written left to right. I think your `>>$` is overkill, though. The `&` operator in `Data.Function` does the job:

```
import Data.Function

foo = [1,2,3] & fmap (+1) & fmap (*2)
```

I like that this says exactly what to start with and exactly what to do at each step from left to right. And unlike `>>$`, you aren't forced to remain in the monad:

```
bar = [1,2,3] & fmap (+1) & fmap (*2) & sum & negate
```

Or you can just assemble your transformation beforehand and map it over your monad:

```
import Control.Category

f = (+1) >>> (*2)
quuz = fmap f [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Good to know about `(&)`. In my particular application (beyond the toy example in my post), I am using the State monad, and I'm actually happy to remain in it.