# Bind function alternative without explicitly returning to Monad

Tags: haskell

I'm just beginning to play with Haskell (just learned the bind function). I like the way it allows to chain subsequent operations left to right inside a Monad.

I'm wondering if there is a way to write the code below more nicely?

```
main = do
    print $ Just 10 
        >>= (\x -> return (x*2))
        >>= (\x -> return (x*3))
```

It feels like the lambdas and return could be replaced with some kind of partially applied function. I was thinking about something like that:

```
(###) :: Maybe Int -> (Int -> Int) -> Maybe Int
(Just x) ### f = Just (f x)
Nothing ### f = Nothing

main = do
    print $ Just 10 
        >>= (\x -> return (x*2))
        >>= (\x -> return (x*3))
        ### (+3) -- the result should be (Just 63)
```

Which of course is ugly, non-generic and doesn't compile :) :

```
monads.hs:8:13:
    Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> Maybe b0'
                with actual type `Maybe Int'
    In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely
      `(\ x -> return (x * 3)) ### (+ 3)'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `Just 10 >>= (\ x -> return (x * 2))
       >>= (\ x -> return (x * 3)) ### (+ 3)'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      print
      $ Just 10 >>= (\ x -> return (x * 2))
        >>= (\ x -> return (x * 3)) ### (+ 3)

monads.hs:8:14:
    Couldn't match expected type `a1 -> m0 a1'
                with actual type `Maybe Int'
    The lambda expression `\ x -> return (x * 3)' has one argument,
    but its type `Maybe Int' has none
    In the first argument of `(###)', namely `(\ x -> return (x * 3))'
    In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely
      `(\ x -> return (x * 3)) ### (+ 3)'
```

Anyway, it seems to be a useful tool, to be able to chain a sequence of operations inside a monad without worrying too much about intermediate results (no do-notation) and without explicitly instructing the code when to fallback to Nothing.

1. Is there a built-in function for that?
2. If not, how should I change my `###` function to be generic, dandy and compile?

Comment: Your `(###)` is essentially flipped `fmap`. The type of `fmap` is `Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`; it becomes `(a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b` once you specialise it to `Maybe`. See also [this somewhat similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42674517/2751851).

Comment: Note that [`(<&>)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.3/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:-60--38--62-) is a generalized version of `(###)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Congratulations, you just invented `Functor`s! Check out the [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-652) for the `Functor` instance for `Maybe`:

```
instance  Functor Maybe  where
    fmap _ Nothing       = Nothing
    fmap f (Just a)      = Just (f a)
```

It is one of the lesser-mentioned monad laws that `m >>= return . f = fmap f m` -- a sort of "coherence" law between the monad actions and the functor action.

`fmap` also has an infix alias, `(<$>)`, so you could write

```
main = print ((+3) <$> (*2) <$> (*3) <$> Just 10)
```

and this outputs `Just 63`.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling it had something to do with Functors :) I didn't like the right to left processing order though. `<&>` mentioned in a comment by Alec solves the problem.